# Cómo contar letras de un archivo de texto?

Tags: java, archivo

Hola verán tengo un ejercicio de JAVA el cual tiene que leer un archivo de texto escrito en el bloc de notas, y anotar cuantas lineas empiezan con cada letra del abecedario.

Es decír, digamos que en la línea 1 del bloc, la linea empieza con "a", entonces el contador aumenta 1 para "a", sigue por linea y por linea buscando cuantas lineas empiezan por la letra "a" y al terminar el contador imprime en la pantalla cuantas lineas empezaron con la letra "a". 
Ahora digamos que como ya contó las de la "a", ahora quiero que cuente cuantas letras empiezan con la letra "b", entonces hace los mismo, busca cuantas lineas empiezan por "b", y al final le dice al usuario... y así en cada letra.

El problema está en que todas las lineas con A me las muestra, sin embargo, cuando cambia a las demás letras del abecedario, el contador se queda estancado en 0, diganme por favor que puedo hacer, tengo ratos dandole vueltas pero no encuentro como salír de este fallo. Desde ya gracias!

```
    String abc="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";//abecedario en minuscula
    String ABC="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";//abecedario en mayuscula
    String nombrecancion;//variable que captura la linea del buffer
    int contador=0;//contador de variables
    try
    {
        archivo = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Kenny\\Desktop\\TAREA 2\\Tarea2FiltrarArchivoLetra\\unique_artists.txt");//le doy una direccion al archivo

        if(archivo.ready())//si el archivo está listo
        {
            buffer = new BufferedReader(archivo);//leo el buffer enviandole el archivo
            for(int i=0; i<26; i++)//hago un ciclo que controlará las palabras del abecedario
            {   
                while((lectorbuffer = buffer.readLine())!=null)//mientras el lector del buffer sea diferente de vacío
                {

                    nombrecancion=lectorbuffer;//guarde lo que encuentre el lector del buffer
                    /*Si el nombre de la cancion en la posicion 0 del string es igual a la letra del abecedario dada por la variable i del for, entonces 
                    aumentará en 1 el contador*/
                    if((nombrecancion.charAt(0) == abc.charAt(i)) || (nombrecancion.charAt(0) == ABC.charAt(i)))
                    {
                        contador++;
                    }
                }
                //irá imprimiendo cuantas canciones habrá con cada letra del abecedario, despues de haber acumulado en la variable contador
                System.out.println("Hay "+contador+" canciones con la letra "+abc.charAt(i)+"/"+ABC.charAt(i));
                contador=0;//reinicio el contador para que cuando entre al while las demás veces esté en su valor incial

            }
            archivo.close();//cierra el archivo
            buffer.close();//cierra el buffer
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Qué tiene que ver el lenguaje `c` con tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas que corregir.

Tener el array en mayúsculas y minúsculas es innecesario. Existen métodos para transformar una cadena en mayúsculas o minúsculas, con lo cual tener uno solo alcanzaría.

y ahora, sigamos la lógica de lo que escribiste.

```
for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
{
```

vas a iterar 26, debería ser sobre la misma linea

```
while((lectorbuffer = buffer.readLine())!=null)
{
```

ahora lees una línea..

```
nombrecancion=lectorbuffer;//guarde lo que encuentre el lector del buffer
if((nombrecancion.charAt(0) == abc.charAt(i)) || (nombrecancion.charAt(0) == ABC.charAt(i)))
```

Te fijas si la primer letra es igual a la primer letra de que? del for de afuera. Está perfecto... pero.. en algún momento tenes que volver a empezar..

```
{
    contador++;
}
```

Estarías contando solo las a en la primer vuelta

```
} //cerrras el while
System.out.println("Hay "+contador+" canciones con la letra "+abc.charAt(i)+"/"+ABC.charAt(i));
contador=0;
```

Genial, pones el contador en cero.. pero el archivo esta terminado...

y acá cierras el for.. o sea.. no vas a leer mas líneas...

Al terminar tu while, y dentro de tu for, tenes que volver al inicio de tu archivo.

Y revisa también string.ToUpper (por ejemplo para transformar solo a mayúscula)

Comment: Muy Cierto, gracias por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando reinicias el contador, deberías reiniciar el buffer de tal manera:

```
contador = 0; //Reinicio del contador
buffer = new BufferedReader(archivo);
archivo = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Kenny\\Desktop\\TAREA 2\\Tarea2FiltrarArchivoLetra\\unique_artists.txt");
```

En tu código, cuando vuelvas a repetir el bucle para leer la siguiente letra, detectará que está en la última línea del archivo y no leerá nada.